# Atualizar preço dentro de um box com jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho uma página com vários boxes contendo algumas informações e o preço do produto, uma URL e um select, quando a pessoa selecionar uma opção diferente no select o preço do produto vai ser alterado. Procurei na internet e encontrei alguns exemplo que poderiam funcionar, no entanto entanto funcionava somente em um bloco.

Por exemplo nesse servidor 01, tem esse valor de 30 e uma URL, mas ao selecionar a opção linux esse valor alterar e também a URL.

```css
.boxe{
float:left;
border: solid 1px #ccc;
margin:15px;
padding:15px;
min-width:135px;
text-align:center
}
.boxe .valor{
font-size:18px;
margin: 15px 0;
font-weight:700;
}

.boxe .url{
display:block;
margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxe">
    <span class="nomePtoduto">
        Servidor 01
    </span>
    <div class="valor" data-vl="30" data-vl-w="35">30</div>
    <select>
        <option>Linux</option>
        <option>Windows</option>
    </select>
    <span class="url">
        <a href="linux.html" data-url="linux.html" data-url-w="windows.html">Comprar</a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="boxe">
    <span class="nomePtoduto">
        Servidor 02
    </span>
     <div class="valor" data-vl="45" data-vl-w="50">45</div>
    <select>
        <option>Linux</option>
        <option>Windows</option>
    </select>
    <span class="url">
         <a href="linux.html" data-url="linux.html" data-url-w="windows.html">Comprar</a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="boxe">
    <span class="nomePtoduto">
        Servidor 03
    </span>
     <div class="valor" data-vl="50" data-vl-w="55">50</div>
    <select>
        <option>Linux</option>
        <option>Windows</option>
    </select>
    <span class="url">
         <a href="linux.html" data-url="linux.html" data-url-w="windows.html">Comprar</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem simples isso, dispare um evento ao mudar o SO, e capte a url e o valor, preencha os dados:

```js
$(document).on('change','.SO-select',function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var box = $(this).find(':selected').data('box');
  var url = $(this).find(':selected').data('url')

  $('.SO-valor[data-box="'+box+'"').html(val);
  $('.SO-link[data-box="'+box+'"').attr('href',url)
});
```

```css
.boxe{
float:left;
border: solid 1px #ccc;
margin:15px;
padding:15px;
min-width:150px;
text-align:center
}
.boxe .valor{
font-size:18px;
margin: 15px 0;
font-weight:700;
}

.boxe .url{
display:block;
margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxe">
    <span class="nomePtoduto">
        Servidor 01
    </span>
    <div class="SO-valor" data-box='1'>30</div>
    <select class='SO-select'>
        <option value='30' data-box='1' data-url='url-linux'>Linux</option>
        <option value='50' data-box='1'data-url='url-windows'>Windows</option>
    </select>
    <span class="url">
        <a href="linux.html" class="SO-link" data-box='1'>Comprar</a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="boxe">
    <span class="nomePtoduto">
        Servidor 02
    </span>
    <div class="SO-valor" data-box='2'>45</div>
    <select class="SO-select">
        <option value='45' data-box='2' data-url='url-linux-2'>Linux</option>
        <option value='55' data-box='2' data-url='url-windows-2'>Windows</option>
    </select>
    <span class="url">
        <a href="linux.html" class="SO-link" data-box='2'>Comprar</a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="boxe">
    <span class="nomePtoduto">
        Servidor 03
    </span>
    <div class="SO-valor" data-box='3'>50</div>
    <select class="SO-select">
        <option value='40' data-box='3' data-url='url-linux-3'>Linux</option>
        <option value='50'  data-box='3' data-url='url-windows-3'>Windows</option>
    </select>
    <span class="url">
        <a href="linux.html" class="SO-link" data-box='3'>Comprar</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Caramba, quem sabe sabe rsrs, cara não teria uma forma de simplificar isso? pois no que eu vou precisar existe muito blocos, se for usar uma função para cada bloco fica trash, uma forma que ele identifica automaticamente o boxe usando apenas uma função, tem como isso?

Comment: Tem sim, assim que eu tiver um tempinho ja atualizo a resposta a tarde.

Comment: Blz cara, valeu mesmo

Comment: e aí cara, tudo bem? conseguiu atualizar?

Comment: Da uma olhada, só ver o attr 'data-box' que vais entender o mecanismo

Comment: valeu mesmo cara, muito obrigado